# MySQL how to add a query to fill a MySQL variable

Tags: mysql

Maybe simple but for me i don't know how add a query to fill a variable @lastValue for the first iteration of the "loop".

Here is the query how it looks like now:

```
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(time,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00') as time, SUM(diff) as value
FROM (select
             EL.time,
             EL.value,
             if(@lastSN = EL.sensor_id, EL.value - @lastValue, 0.0) as diff,
             @lastSN := EL.sensor_id,
             @lastValue := EL.value
      FROM data_test_debug EL, (SELECT @lastSN := 0,
                                @lastValue := 0) SQLVars
      WHERE EL.sensor_id = "ecam"
      AND EL.value_id = "gas"
      ORDER BY EL.time
     ) AS t
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(time,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');
```

The value of the variable @lastValue is in first iteration **0.0** as defined.

**Problem** -> i have to fill till this value by another SELECT query how can i achieve this? for this example we can keep it simple like:

```
SELECT lastValue from table WHERE id=1
```

thx for helping

Answer (score 0):

Use another inline view, just like the `SQLVars` did for the other variables. Or you could just modify the SQLVars view.

e.g.

```
  FROM data_test_debug EL
 CROSS 
  JOIN ( SELECT @lastSN := 0 ) SQLVars
 CROSS
  JOIN ( SELECT @lastValue := t.lastvalue 
           FROM table t 
          WHERE t.id=1
          ORDER BY t.id, t.lastvalue
          LIMIT 1
       ) lv
```

---

I strongly encourage ditching the old-school comma syntax for the join operation, and replacing that with the newer `JOIN` keyword.  With MySQL, the `CROSS` keyword isn't necessary, but I think it does give the future reader an indication that the omission of the `ON` clause is intentional.

---

It doesn't have to be two separate inline views, this would achieve the same result:

```
  FROM data_test_debug EL
 CROSS
  JOIN ( SELECT @lastSN := 0
              , @lastValue := t.lastvalue
           FROM table t
          WHERE t.id=1
          ORDER BY t.id, t.lastvalue
          LIMIT 1
       ) lv
```

We would want to use separate inline views if we needed to set multiple variables based on separate queries.